# String replace in var with jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I am having trouble trying to get all my form data and break it down for debugging. I just want to replace the "&" with a new line.

```
var formData = $("#customer_details_form").serialize();  
var debugData = formData.text().replace(/&/g,'\n');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `formData` has the string, so `text()` shouldn't be necessary.
Try `formData.replace(/&/g,'\n');`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried that and didnt work so I looked a little harder. I had vars debugData and debug_data. lol thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery's `.serialize()` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns a String, not a jQuery object, so get rid of `.text()`.

```
var formData = $("#customer_details_form").serialize();  
var debugData = formData.replace(/&/g,'\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

`formData` is an ordinary string.
Remove the `.text()` call.